# Is a way I can render CSS/Javascript bundles without using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

The only thing that my code uses which requires ASP.NET MVC is:

```
<<< HTML here >>>
<body>
    <<< Some HTML here >>>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/textview")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Angular")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/AngularApp")
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a sample from my BundleConfig.cs

```
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
       "~/Content/css/*.css"
    ));
```

The ability to render the CSS in debug or release is really good but I want to move completely away from using MVC and just use and index.html page and ASP.NET Web API.  Is there a way that I can get similar functionality with rendering bundles without using a controller?

Comment: Have you looked at Cassette? http://getcassette.net/

Comment: Cassette looks interesting. I would be interested to hear if any posters here have used or heard of cassette? Thanks

Comment: @levelnis - I spent time looking into cassette and I'm concerned. There are many issue there in the github and it seems like there's not much activity going on. It's important for me to use some software that's supported and I don't get a good feeling about Cassette. Thanks for your advice but I think I need to try another way.

Comment: Interesting - thanks for the heads up @marifemac. I've not personally used Cassette but had heard good things about it. That was a year or so back though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two things:

1. You already create a virtual path to these bundles so you can access them externally.
2. You can create your html pages using the Razor view engine, and by doing that, get the "strength" of the Razor engine for things like bundles - You simple create a route that will help you server your static files from a single action.

lets say the routing will be:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "HTMLViewRoute",
                url: "Htmls/{*pathInfo}",
                defaults: new { controller = "HTMLFileRouting", action = "ViewRoute"});
```

In the route take the pathinfo and find the path to your html file(using Server.MapPath) and return View(filePath,null) since you need no model.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. However I am pretty new to this technology. I'm not sure for example what to do when you say "You can create your html pages using the Razor view engine". Can I do this without having ASP.NET installed and how do I do that ? I think maybe you are on the right track for an answer but I am still not sure how to do a lot. Can you add a few more lines to explain. Thanks

Comment: Your server is asp.net(web api). Now you want your client to be just plain htmls so you can work with a client side framework(e.g. AngularJS) right? So you have some bundles and when you create the bundles you create a virtual path(~/bundles/css in your case) so you can access them from your clear htmls, but from what I remember, you get them minimized only and lack some other features the the RenderBundle function gives you.
So, if thats so important to you, you can render your plain html files with the razor view engine and by that get some more strength.

Comment: The problem with doing that is that you are binded to using dot.net.
So, maybe an external bundle framework could do stuff better for you, but if you insist, this is a way to do stuff.

Comment: @Amiros - One person suggested cassette. I started to look at that now. Do you think that would be a good alternative? Also you mention "render your plain html files with the razor view engine" can you tell me how I could do that. Thanks

Comment: Amiros - Sorry to keep asking the same question but you mention "render your plain html files with the razor view engine". Can you tell me how I could do that. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Add a route to your routing that will server your "static html files". Each request to <server>/Html/<file path> will get there.
The route will send you to a default controller and action.
The action will look at the <file path> and search the server for the file location(using Server.MapPath). If the file isn't found, throw an exception. If it is simply return View(filepath,null).
You return a View(the Razor view engine will render it, so you can add any dot net stuff you want in the view) and the "null" is since you dont have a model on your "plain" html files.