# ASP.NET MVC CSS fails

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

CSS wizards, show me the light please. Trying to apply my own stylesheet (table formatting) in an MVC project but I think I'm missing something as nothing happens.

index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/mystuff.css">
```

BundleConfig:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Content/mystuff.css"));
```

Despite this setup, bootstrap still seems to override my own settings. Am I missing any reference? Thanks a bunch

Comment: You don't actually need the BundleConfig, you can just include your css in your master page or wherever you want to include it.

Comment: well, erm, thanks, tried it, but the computer says no

Comment: Check your browser console what's really happening, your path might be wrong because in my project I don't use the BundleConfig.

Comment: What order are the files defined & loaded? Bootstrap should be first, last file to be loaded will be the one that has styling applied to specified elements. It works on `bottom-up` principles.

Comment: Adriani6, files are defined and loaded in the order you can see it in the question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in a css files you have !important attribute after a property.

Like:

```
 color:red !important;
```

and in this case, even if you add a new class or modify the style of html element and put for exemple

```
 color:yellow;
```

the browser will override your yellow color.
try to put !important after your css property to see what it will do.

If it doesn't work, by pressing F12 key you can show the tools window and examine your html element to be sure if it takes properties of your new css file.

Comment: thanks Coskun, this indeed might a bit problem. just had a look at the bootstrap and a million of table attributes are marked as !important over there. should I add !important after every single line in my stylsheet to make sure it overrides bs's deafult settings? this would be quite painful

Comment: Yes, you are right, but unfortunately I don't know how can you make your stylesheet completely important. If you find the solution, please share it.

Comment: @CoskunOzogul Do you even know what `!important` is, what it does? Putting it over everything is not recommended and should be avoided.

Comment: @Adriani6, I didn't say to put it after everything. I said that if a css property was marked !important, to override it you should use !important.

Answer (score 0):

You must Render this bundle inside the View.
 `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")`

You can also use dev tools that mozilla offers and see each element in order to understand where Override can happen.

If you want to override bootstrap, use media queries (selectors). Example:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks Indrit, I tried as you suggested but it still takes no effect :(

Comment: Do you have just a css problem with some elements? or css file is not yet included in index?

Comment: If you are not using Views (Razor) you don't need bundles. Just include them in html file as external. Or you can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23269641/is-a-way-i-can-render-css-javascript-bundles-without-using-asp-net-mvc